# Adding regex strings in vb.net

Tags: regex, vb.net, listview, search, mp3

I have a string and I can find the following

- Kbps
- Duration
- Mb
- Song Title

Website
http://abmp3.com/

I can't seem to find the URL i used Expresso to create the regex and used the source from the webpage to get matches but for some reason when i add this href="(.*.mp3)" to the end of the string it won't find anything. The kbps,duration,and mb are on all on the same line. The Song Title is on a different line and so is the URL

My question is how would you add the href="(.*.mp3)" to the end of the regex string?

Regex Code

```
":6px;"">(.* Kbps)<br>(.*)<br> (.* Mb)</div></td>\D+\S+<strong>(.*) mp3"
```

Need to add this to the end

```
href="(.*.mp3)"
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide sample input and what do you want to get from your ReGex?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the website, it appears this would work for you:

```
href=\".*\.mp3\"
```